# how to optimize Mysql query computing dates and min/max/average?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've a table of measurements with timestamp. One data each 5 minutes.
I've created a view to extract average/min/max values for every 30minutes. Problem is I found this query very slow (+/- 5 s for total of 13290 rows... which is very few..

Any idea of optimisation ?

My code:

```
SELECT t_mesures.sonde_id AS sonde_id
    ,min(t_mesures.timestamp) AS start_period
    ,max(t_mesures.timestamp) AS end_period
    ,from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(min(t_mesures.timestamp))+
        floor( (unix_timestamp(max(t_mesures.timestamp))-unix_timestamp(min(t_mesures.timestamp)))/2)
     ) AS mid_period
    ,timediff(max(t_mesures.timestamp), min(t_mesures.timestamp)) AS dur_period  
    ,avg(t_mesures.Mesure) AS avg_mesure
    ,min(t_mesures.Mesure) AS min_mesure
    ,max(t_mesures.Mesure) AS max_mesure
    ,count(t_mesures.Mesure) as nb_mesure
FROM t_mesures
GROUP BY t_mesures.sonde_id
    ,(floor((unix_timestamp(t_mesures.timestamp) / 1800)) * 1800)
```

Comment: This topic is not related with Highcharts, because it is only SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already noticed, calculating these things live tends to get pretty heavy.

The best way to make sure you don't have this problem is by simply not calculating it. In addition to storing the 5 minute interval data you should also store the 30 minutes min/max/avg/count data (and/or any other interval you're going to use).

Alternatively, you could also try something like [Whisper](http://graphite.wikidot.com/whisper), [RRD](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) or [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/)

Comment: do you mean launch another cron task to update a new table containing consolidated values ? one table for 30min average, one table for 3hours average and a third one for dayly average. MySQL DB size will not explode ? bug DB cannot make the query slower ?

Comment: Either a new cronjob or calculate it on the fly. You can easily do these things using a stored procedure although I'm not sure if that's an easy solution with MySQL. And yes, it will take a bit more storage, but not _that_ much more. This way you can also remove the old data, for example... for old data you might not need it with 5 minute accuracy anymore but 30mins is enough.

Comment: My query above was indeed to compute this 30min average . So I don't see the advantage to use a store proc

Comment: You could have a stored procedure on your normal table to automatically update the summary data when adding a new row. The `MAX()` can be handled with `GREATEST()`, the `COUNT()` is simply a `+1`, etc...